# What is this cryptically-named cookie being generated by Laravel?

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-sanctum

[image: The cookie in question]

This is less a problem, and more the fact that I would appreciate understanding what purpose it serves.

The project is a headless Laravel instance with cookie-driven Sanctum auth, and Tenancy for Laravel installed (Github/stancl).

There doesn't appear to be any information on said cookie in Laravel, or Tenancy for Laravel's documentation, so hoping I might be able to gather some insight on it here.

Comment: I think this is just the cookie, duplicated and encrypted. It happens in `Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies`. You should be able to confirm this if this cookie disappears  when you disable the `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies` middleware in `app/Http/kernel.php`.

Comment: I'm just speculating here: I suppose it's purpose if to make sure the session cookie isn't forged? If your APP_KEY gets compromised, it might be. If you were to change the APP_KEY, then this encrypted cookie would be invalidated?

Comment: @IGP I appreciate your response. Removing the middleware, in both Sanctum's config and in Kernal, doesn't seem to stop that cookie from being generated. Dumping the new and old cookie names on the Duplicate method of EncryptCookies doesn't indicate the name is changed either, just the value. I think you are probably on the mark with the purpose, but skeptical of the origin